# How does CMake check for IPO support?

Tags: gcc, cmake, clang, lto

I'm trying to use CMake 3.10 to build a C++ application with IPO, I have the following in my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include(CheckIPOSupported)
check_ipo_supported(RESULT ipo_supported)
if(ipo_supported)
    message("-- IPO is supported!")
    set_property(TARGET target PROPERTY INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION TRUE)
else()
    message(WARNING "IPO is not supported!")
endif()
```

I'm using GCC 7.2 configured with IPO enabled (default) on a CentOS 4 machine, and I am able to compile a simple test program with the `-flto` flag. Yet CMake reports IPO is not supported. On multiple other machines the same CMake script reports IPO is supported.

It would help me to understand what the problem is if I knew how CMake checks for IPO support. How does the CMake's module [`CheckIPOSupported`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/CheckIPOSupported.html) work?

Comment: According to the module's documentation, you may pass additional option `OUTPUT <output>` to the macro and check the reason why it fails. (Alternatively, you may remove RESULT option, so fail reason will be printed by CMake).

Answer (score 4):

Add `OUTPUT output` to your CheckIPO call:

```
check_ipo_supported(RESULT ipo_supported OUTPUT output)
```

You can print out `output` to get the reason why it is not supported.

Usually, failing tests leave traces in the file `CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log` within the CMake build directory. Check the according entry to learn more why a test failed.

Finally, to answer your actual question how CheckIPOSupported work: Read the code! You can find it online https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Modules/CheckIPOSupported.cmake
You can even add additional output statements in your local copy, if you have difficulties to understand every detail.